# What machine learning algorithm should I use for a dataset of which its logica is unknown?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a hypothetical machine learning question. Ideally, I would like to have an answer with a Tensorflow example. The question is programming language agnostic.

**Problem Example A:**

I have training material that looks like this (I have changed its contents to make the question clearer).

Training data:

```
[{
    "a": 564356,
    "b": 23463246
}, {
    "a": 723572575,
    "b": 45472
}, {
    "a": 1351345,
    "b": 0943563456
}, {
    "a": 12523635,
    "b": 3249582345
}, etcetera...]
```

I would like to provide data like this (aka "The Input"):

```
[{
    "a": 232346,
    "b": 373457
}, {
    "a": 36458,
    "b": 5674567
}, etcetera...]
```

And have returned data like this (aka: "The Answer"):

```
[{
    "a": 113424,
    "b": 5674567
}, {
    "a": 15345,
    "b": 5678
}, etcetera...]
```

**Problem Example B**:

I have training material that looks like this (I have changed its contents to make the question clearer).

Training data:

```
[{
    "q": "What animal do you like",
    "a": "Dog"
}, {
    "q": "What is your favorite color",
    "a": "Blue"
}, {
    "q": "Do you like beer as a drink",
    "a": "Yes"
}, {
    "q": "Do you have a color you like",
    "a": "Green"
}, etcetera...]
```

I would like to provide data like this (aka "The Input"):

```
[{
    "q": "What color do you like",
    "a": "Yellow"
}, etcetera...]
```

And have returned data like this (aka: "The Answer"):

```
[{
    "q": "What is your favorite color",
    "a": "Yellow"
}, etcetera...]
```

*Please note that I'm not trying to have the algorithm answer the question, but to come with a logical Q and A in response.*

**Question**:
What training algorithm should I use to train a model against an unknown logic (the training data above) so that when I provide "The Input" it will return with an answer (like in: "The Answer").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what tensorflow supports,  but generally for such problems you should use unsupervised learning algorithms.

If you have a lot of training data kNN would give you reasonable performance.  Although for your second use case you should thing of good way to break up question sentences.  I'd start with simple conversion to word bags, and go from there.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad. Would this mean that, by using unsupervised learning algorithms, a logical response (aka The Answer) would return based on the input (aka The Input)?

Comment: Yes.  Unsupervised algorithms are used when you don't have any class labels on your input data and you are trying to uncover the underlying structure.  In most algorithms the structure remains buried within model parameters.  But you can ask your model questions like 'what is the closest item/class to this new item I just got'.  Which seems to be exactly like your case.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate

Comment: Just a side note - kNN is not "unsupervised" in any sense. Unless you mean 1NN, but then again, it is supervised - simply label the point itself.